# Android RelativeLayout, hiding views and pushing the views beneath up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` which includes a `Spinner` and some `RadioButton`s, based on the selection of these I have to hide some views and make others visible. The problem is if I make the views `GONE` by `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` the layout gets messed up, the views overlap, if I use `view.Visibility(View.INVISIBLE)` everything is fine but the missing views create a void on the page. I want to push the views beneath up to properly augment the page. Below is a better explanation:

[image]

[image]

So far the code I have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_app" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drop_down" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_calendar"
                android:textColor="#FFBF00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:ems="6"
                android:hint="xx xx"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:textColor="#002f44" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:padding="03dp"
                android:textColor="#610B0B" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="xxx "
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/widget_style"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:ems="8"
                android:hint="xx xx"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#002f44" >
            </AutoCompleteTextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textColor="#002f44"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [alignWithParentIfMissing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignWithParentIfMissing) attribute.

I've reworked your layout, try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFBF00" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:ems="6"
                    android:hint="xx xx"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:textColor="#002f44" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                    android:padding="03dp"
                    android:textColor="#610B0B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="xxx "
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio0"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="xxx"
                        android:textColor="#002f44" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:text="xxx"
                        android:textColor="#002f44" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:ems="8"
                    android:hint="xx xx"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#002f44" >
                </AutoCompleteTextView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button01"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button02"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textColor="#002f44"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I had tried that attribute brfore posting, however it will just push the views to be aligned with the parent. which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use LinearLayout(vertical) inside ScrollView and create RelativeLayouts as child of this LinearLayout. Set height of these RelativeLayout as wrap content, so that as you set visibility of items as GONE its height will shrink.

Now as per image that you have given here, you can have spinner first then below that a relative layout which will contain two (horizontal) items that you wanna hide. then next two (horizontal) items in another layout and then your image, editText and Button in third layout.
So you hide any relative layout others will arrange properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create a `view` of height `1dp` with transparent background below `texView4` and then set `android:layout_below="@id/view"` attribute for `textView5`. Here is how the changes to the layout would look like:

```
</RadioGroup> <!-- RadioGroup ends -->

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
    android:background="@color/transparent"/>

<!-- Changed layout_below attribute value -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@id/view"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="xxx"
    android:textColor="#002f44"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

And here is how the layout looks like with `textView4` and `RadioGroup` gone:

[image]